# People Picker Field not working under SP2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

We have a custom list app and under SP2016 all the people picker fields are not working...

Most people are getting a 'JSON" is undefined

Click the OK and then you can put in a name in the dialog box but it just spins

Help !!!!!

Comment: Check the people picker control works in another browser to see if it is the browser issue. If you are using IE 11, check if the people picker control works in IE 10 mode. Open it in Internet Explorer and then press F12, click Browser Mode, choose IE 10.

Comment: okay tried that... in f12 mode default pops up people picker screen but gets JSON error, IE10 does nothing when icon is clicked same with all others

Answer (score 1):

1)In the IE, click on the Settings icon then click on "Compatibility View Settings". In the Compatibility View Settings page uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" as shown in the fig below:[image]

Now close your browser and try again. It should resolve the issue.

2)From the Tools menu in IE check if "Enterprise Mode" is unchecked or not. If it is not unchecked please uncheck it. It should appear like below:
[image]

Then close the browser and try again. it should solve the issue.